# angular "Unable to extract routes" when using ng run prerender and generated routes

Tags: json, angular, routes, server-side-rendering

I am trying to generate routes from json file as I have generic view, which based on json data will create separate view with unique slug also based on this json file there are also sitemaps generated, so its used for two purposes.

generic_pages.json

```
{
    INDUSTRIES: [
     {
       template: {
          title: 'page title',
          bannerPath: 'assets/banners/bann.jpg'
       },
       path: 'industry-name',
       ...
      },
      {
       template: {
          title: 'other page title',
          bannerPath: 'assets/banners/other-bann.jpg'
       },
       path: 'other-industry'
      },
      ....
    ]
}
```

and now I am importing this json to routing module, and mapping those routes and pass template to data in following way:

app.routing.module.ts

```
import  *  as  genericPages  from  './generic_pages.json';

const industriesPages = genericPages.INDUSTRIES_PAGES.map(page => ({
  path: page.path,
  loadChildren: () => import('./components/pages/industry-page/industry-page.module').then(m => m.IndustryPageModule),
  data: {
    title: page.meta.title ? page.meta.title : '',
    description: page.meta.description ? page.meta.description : '',
    industryTemplate: page.template
  }
}));

const routes: Routes = [ ... , ...industriesPages}

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabled',
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and those routes are working properly, when i run `ng serve` or `ng run app:serve-ssr`, they are seen and I can access them by URL directly.
The prob exists only when I deploy app, and there is `ng run app:prerender`, which throws error `Unable to extract routes`, and on server those routes aren't seen when i want to enter them directly by pasting url (such as domain.com/industry-name) to browser, but when I enter `domain.com` and click links I can access those routes, and also I noticed when those routes are hardcoded in `const routes: Routes = [...]` everything is ok, error only occurs when I am mapping and then concatenating to `const routes`, and also noticed when i erase `loadChildren` prop from mapping it stops throwing this error.